# Unable to execute js call __fbbatchedbridge is undefined under debug mode

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I just deployed my app into App store.

Now I want to go back to my app in Debug mode and make some changes.

What I did was change the build process in product schema from release to debug.

Then I got the following error message:

unable to execute js call __fbbatchedbridge is undefined

Anyone know what is going on? It is working beautifully under release mode.

Cheers

Comment: I have got a file called main.jsbundle in my project directory. does it matter. should I delete it and run again?

Comment: And also. I can get into debug mode by just issusing the following command.

react-native run-ios

But can't get into the debug mode from Xcode

Comment: Could you mention your react-native version you are using?

Comment: The version is "react-native": "^0.29.0".

I can get into debug mode just by runing `react-native run-ios` but can't make it work within Xcode. And I changed the name of the project before but it failed. Wondering if that is the problem.